# What's the difference between the Add and Linear Dodge blend modes in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, blend-modes

What's the difference between the Add and Linear Dodge blend modes in After Effects? Aren't they the same thing? [The user guide page](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/blending-modes-layer-styles.html) isn't of much help because it doesn't specify the differences in the math used for these two modes, but from what I understand, Linear Dodge is Add in Photoshop for example (hence the label "Linear Dodge (Add)"), and from what I see they behave exactly alike in After Effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the way two these modes behave when a layer isn't fully opaque. `Linear Dodge` behaves as lowering *Opacity* in Photoshop, while `Add` behaves as lowering *Fill*. I believe they're separated in AE because there's no Fill parameter in it. I think it's the same for `Color Dodge`/`Classic Color Dodge` and `Color Burn`/`Classic Color Burn`

[image]